# how to access my Visualforce & lightning page without authentication?

Tags: visualforce, community

I have one Visualforce page & one lightning page in my community. Currently I'm able to access my VF page without authentication. I have created new lightning page which I need to access without authentication. Is it possible to access both VFpage & Lightning page without authentication at a time?

My requirement is both the pages should be able to access without Salesforce authentication. After clicking  submit button in each page should take me to Community portal page for further registration.

Thanks in Advance!!

Comment: For VF pages Go to Setup -> Communities -> All Communities -> click Manage -> Administration -> Pages -> Go to force.com -> Click on public access settings and add your page there. 

**For Lightning** If the component is on a community page which is enabled as `public` you should be able to see that.

Comment: @manjit5190 This really should be an answer.

Comment: I have created a VF page and I called my lightning component into the  VF page. Then I provided the public access to my VF page. So I'm able to access my VF page without authentication